# Why the transform.localPosition never equal to the begin position of the transform?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveScrollView : MonoBehaviour
{
    float seconds;
    Vector3 begin;
    Vector3 end;
    Vector3 difference;

    public static bool go = false;
    public static bool goBack = false;
    public static bool atOriginPos = false;

    void Start()
    {
        seconds = 0.5f;

        begin = transform.localPosition;
        end = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
        difference = end - begin;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            if (transform.localPosition.x < end.x)
            {
                var mx = transform.localPosition.x;
                transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mx += seconds * Time.unscaledTime, -1, 0);
                difference = end + transform.localPosition;
            }
        }

        if(goBack)
        {
            if (transform.localPosition.x > begin.x)
            {
                var mx = transform.localPosition.x;
                transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mx -= seconds * Time.unscaledTime, -1, 0);
                difference = end - transform.localPosition;
            }
        }

        if(transform.localPosition == begin && goBack)
        {
            atOriginPos = true;
        }
    }
}
```

At the Start the begin position is (-540.0, -1.0, 0.0) also the transform.localPosition is at the same position.

Then at this line 39 :

```
if (transform.localPosition.x > begin.x)
```

The value of the x of the transform.localPosition is 3.039021 and the x of the begin is -540
So it's getting inside and move the transform.

Then when the transform has finished moving I see on this line :

```
if (transform.localPosition.x > begin.x)
```

The transform.localPosition x value is -540.7267 and the x value of the begin is still -540
So now it will not get inside and will not move the transform anymore.

But two wrong things happened :

1. The transform stopped moving but it didn't move to it's original position only close to it.
2. Because it didn't move to it's exact original position then the localPosition x and the begin x are never equal so the this will never be true :

   if(transform.localPosition == begin && goBack)

And the flag atOriginPos is never true.

I want the transform to move back to it's original position and then when it's reached the original position set the flag atOriginPos to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving your transforms at a speed that depends on the framerate:

```
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mx += seconds * Time.unscaledTime, -1, 0);
```

That's good because it ensures that the movement speed is steady even if the framerate is inconsistent. However, it means that your transforms are not moving a fixed distance each frame.

Let's say that your movement speed is 60 units/second and the game is trying to render 60 fps per second. Ideally, you render one frame every 1/60th of a second (16ms) and the GameObject moves exactly `1` unit each frame. However, in reality the framerate is going to fluctuate at least a little bit. Maybe one frame takes 21ms to render, and the GameObject moves `1.3125` units that frame. Or the frame only takes 15ms to render and the GameObject moves `.9375` units that frame.

Since the movement we add to our position each frame is a floating point value, it's extremely unlikely that the GameObject is ever going to precisely end up at a specific position. For example, say we started at `x = 0` and want to end up at `x = 5`. We might see movement like this:

1. Move .9375 (total .9375)
2. Move 1.125 (total 2.0625)
3. Move 1 (total 3.0625)
4. Move 1.0625 (total 4.125)
5. Move .9375 (total 5.0625)

In 5 frames, we moved 5.0625 units and did not land exactly on `x = 5`. Worse, even if the framerate is 100% consistent, if our movement distance is not a whole number, we might still not exactly end up at a particular position due to floating-point precision error.

There are two solutions easy to this problem:

#### 1. Use `Vector3.MoveTowards()`.

The [MoveTowards()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) function moves towards a destination by a specific amount, and will never pass the destination.

```
float distanceToMove = speed * Time.unscaledTime;
//We will never move past the end point
transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, end, distanceToMove);
```

#### 2. Don't use an equality comparison for positions

Instead of writing `if (transform.localPosition == begin)`, you can do this:

```
float threshold = .1f; //adjust as needed for more precision
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, end) < threshold) {
    atOriginPos = true;
}
```

Here, instead of checking if our position is *exactly* equal to some position, we check if it's *closer than a certain threshold*. This is much safer, but it is not perfect. If our object moved by more than `threshold` distance in one frame, it might go from one side of the target position to the other without ever being within `threshold` units.

Comment: For the range comparison in this case, I might recommend `if (transform.localPosition.x <= begin.x)` - that way we can overshoot any amount and still trigger the condition correctly.

Comment: @DMGregory That also works, but then we need separate cases for moving left and right. If he wants it to exactly end up at `end`, `Vector3.MoveTowards()` seems like the best bet. That approach works independently of the movement axis/direction.